# How can I re-arrange my code to produce the output I want?

Tags: java

Please could you help me re-arrange my already working code to give me this output described in the bullet points underneath:

- 'Type your text' window appears
- The user enters the text, for example 'hey'
- The code prints out the text entered by the user (hey), underneath the code prints out the number of characters (3) and finally another scanner window 'Type your text' appears. So the program loops back to 2 and waits for another line to be typed.

**This would look like this:**

```
 hey

 3

 another scanner for the text to be typed in
```

My code already works and calculates everything, i just ran out of ideas how to re-arrange it to make its output exactly what i want:

```
    System.out.println("Type your text...");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);


    System.out.println(sc.nextLine());            
    System.out.println(sc.nextLine().length());

    System.out.println("Length of String: " + lengthOfString("hey"));
    sc.close();
}


private static int lengthOfString(String string) {
    int length = -1;
    while (true) {
        try {
            string.charAt(++length);
        } catch (StringIndexOutOfBoundsException exception) {
            break;
        }
    }
    return length;
}
```

I am a beginner and I have weak understanding of java so please be clear with your answers and all your answers will be much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: as it is I don't understand what you're actually asking.

Comment: your first step should be to post a complete sample of code so we can see the entire problem (or even compile it and run it ourselves).  Also be sure to tell us what your are actually seeing as output, in addition to what you want to see.

Comment: I really apologize for unclear post, I am new here and I'm still learning to write my posts clear for the users here, sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have removed unncessary complexity from your code,Try this code:

```
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);       
    String s;
    while(true)  //have created infinite loop as you want to continuously take inputs,
    {
        System.out.println("Enter value:");
        s=sc.next();    
        if(s.equals("quit"))                  //if enterd value is "quit" than it comes out of loop ,termination condition to come out
        {
            break;
        }
        System.out.println(""+s); //to Print string
        System.out.println(""+s.length());  //to print Entered string's length


    }
```

Comment: The `""+` is unnecessary in any of the calls to `System.out.println()`. Also, perhaps it might be better to exit when the user enters an empty line rather than the value "quit".

Answer (score 3):

The main problem is that you are calling `nextLine()` twice when you only want to be calling it once. Instead of these two lines:

```
System.out.println(sc.nextLine());            
System.out.println(sc.nextLine().length());
```

Use this:

```
String input = sc.nextLine();
System.out.println(input);
System.out.println(input.length());
```

Another problem is that you are closing `sc`. This will close the underlying stream (`System.in`), which you don't want to do. Finally, you need to invoke this code in a loop so that the process is repeated. You don't show the context for this code, but I'm assuming that it's in a method that is being called in a loop or is part of the body of a loop. In either case, it would be better to create a `Scanner` once and use it repeatedly, rather than creating and disposing of a `Scanner` for each transaction with the user.

Answer (score 2):

```
while (true)
{
  System.out.println("Type your text...");
  String str = sc.nextLine();
  System.out.println("Length of String: " + str.length());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try out this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CountingOccurences {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner inp= new Scanner(System.in);
    String str;
    char ch;
    int count=0;

    System.out.println("Enter the string:");
    str=inp.nextLine();

    while(str.length()>0)
    {
        count++;
        str.substring(count);
    }
    System.out.println("Length :"+count);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a loop, calling nextLine() twice reads two lines (and throws them away) and don't close your Scanner. `System.in` is a global, if you `close()` your Scanner that will close System.in and it will not reopen.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
while(true) {
  System.out.println("Type your text...");
  // System.out.println(sc.nextLine());          // <-- thrown away!        
  // System.out.println(sc.nextLine().length()); // <-- Second next line call
  String line = sc.nextLine();
  System.out.println("Length of String: " + lengthOfString(line)); // <-- not "hey"
  // sc.close();
}
```

**Edit**

Just read `lengthOfString(String)`, let's fix that -

```
private static int lengthOfString(String string) {
  return string.trim().length();
}
```